# AVS/ASK for iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, api, alexa-skills-kit

AFAIK, [Alexa Voice Service](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service) and [Alexa Skills Kit](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit) are only available for *device*, which is our customized hardware. iOS/Android app, (referred as [companion app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amazon-alexa/id944011620?mt=8), created by Amazon), is mainly for settings, such as:

- Authorize hardware
- Enable/disable skills
- Display graphical
  representation of a [result](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/getting-started-guide) (**Displaying Cards in the
  Alexa App** section)
- ...

Has Amazon released Alexa API on iOS/Android, instead of *device* currently?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Non-Companion Route (AVS App) , go to [AVS App](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/authorizing-your-alexa-enabled-mobile-app)

Just for clarification, There are two different methods to communicate to Alexa.

**Companion App**

(You have a device (such as a smart speaker) that you want to add Alexa to. So, you build in support for AVS. Great! Now you need a way to authorize it and associate it with the user's account. This is the "companion app" approach. The companion app connects to your smart product and allows the user to login and authorize the speaker to use Alexa and connect to their Amazon account.)

- [Mobile](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/authorizing-your-alexa-enabled-product-from-an-android-or-ios-mobile-app)

  - [Website](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/authorizing-your-alexa-enabled-product-from-a-website)

**AVS App**

(You don't have a device you need to authorize - instead you want to speak to Alexa from within your Android/Iphone application.)

[Mobile](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/authorizing-your-alexa-enabled-mobile-app)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I have an Amazon Echo Dot. I need to connect to that device from my android app and invoke Alexa. Is that possible?